# Validating html sliders

Tags: html, django, slider

I am very new to programming and I am working on an online experiment with Django.

We are using sliders extensively throughout the experiment as an input device, and we need to find a way to validate the sliders to make sure our participants actually moved/clicked on the sliders somehow.

The form input should be integers, and I have tried:
1. clearing the starting value
2. setting the starting value to a decimal so it won't pass integer check when submitting the form(it passed anyway for some reason) 
3. setting the starting value to a string (broke the slider altogether)

Got no joy from any of these methods.

I am using carpe custom slider to remove the hovering number when dragging the slider. http://carpe.ambiprospect.com/slider/

Here are my codes:
HTML:

```
<div class="form-group {% if form.trust.errors %}has-error {% endif %}">
<label class="control-label" for="trust">Your Trust</label>
<input
id="trust"
name="trust"
type="range"
style="width: 300px;"
tabindex="0"
min="0"
max="100"
step="1"
value="50.111111111111111111"
data-carpe-decimals="0"
value="{{form.trust.value}}"/>
</div>
<div class="btn_block">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" alt="proceed to next page">Next</button>
</div>
```

forms.py:

```
class TaskbeginForm(forms.Form):
    trust = forms.IntegerField()
```

As I am very new to html and know nothing about javascript, please treat me like a pre-schooler and I can probably only understand very simple solutions.

Comment: Please validate the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your input tag is not closing:

`<input id="trust" name="trust" type="range" style="width: 300px;" tabindex="0" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="50.111111111111111111" data-carpe-decimals="0" value="{{form.trust.value}}"/>`

2. There are two values attributed to the input value="50.111111111111111111" and value="{{form.trust.value}}.
3. Don't you have to insert the percentage between the value tag?
   value="{{form.trust.value}}, it should be value={%form.trust.value%}, I'm guessing that this returns a string.

Comment: 1. You are right. I was trying to take out some unused codes and accidentally took out the closing as well. 2. The first value was set when I was experimenting to see whether setting the initial value to a decimal could invalidate the form. It didn't work though, and the line serves no purpose right now. 3. As for value tag, I am using https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/templates/ as a guidance and they used {{ instead of {% around values.

Comment: Did it solve the problem? If not, feel free to comment :)

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the late response! Unfortunately this doesn't solve all of my problems. I need to implement some form of validation of input so that the participants have to interact with the slider before moving on. Currently, if participants don't interact with the slider, the project would use the default value "50" and allow them to proceed to the next page.

Comment: Check if the value is different than the default before moving on, if it's different then someone interacted with it

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response! I think this might be doable! I am thinking about changing the form for this one to a decimalfield and set a default value very near 50 but not exactly 50 (so it looks like the dragger starts at the middle while it's slightly off). Now I have another question, sorry. How do I check this value? Can I check it with html or javascript (I haven't learned JS yet) or is it something I have to do in Django (I am not good at it but I can try)? Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend you learning React To build frontend apps. It&#39;s a Javascript framework, on node js. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/next/README.md#creating-an-app. Js it&#39;s not that hard and a must skill for web. Check out the official docs and start doing the tutorial: https://reactjs.org/. Django is great, but I prefer using it on the backend side. I would apreciate that you mark my answer as answering your questions. Thanks and use React, you will fell in love with it.